# Powercenter 10x "Error : Session cannot be aborted or restarted"

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am working on one of the Powercenter 10x Transformations & Workflows and faced this error and unable to view the session logs and the emtire system is not stuck, everytime i have to force restart my laptop.I am having pretty much good configuration on my laptop with 32 GB RAM and 1 TB SSD hard disk. I even tried to recycle the integration services, but even that was also stuck and not responsive, any help is much appreciated.

> (Thread 0x53deb940 (LWP 28161)):
>       0x000000385a87aefe in memcpy () from /lib64/libc.so.6
>       0x00002ba5bfb20def in zstrbuf::expand() () from /opt/infa/pc/v901/server/bin/libpmuti.so
>       0x00002ba5bfb20e5d in zstrbuf::overflow(int) () from /opt/infa/pc/v901/server/bin/libpmuti.so
>       0x00002ba5bfb1ee2a in zstreambuf::xsputn(unsigned short const*, int) () from 
>       /opt/infa/pc/v901/server/bin/libpmuti.so
>       0x00002ba5bfb1e817 in zostream::write(unsigned short const*, int) () from 
>       /opt/infa/pc/v901/server/bin/libpmuti.so
>       0x00000000005d9bdc in sendEMail(PmUString const&, PmUString const&, PmUString const&, 
>       PMTValOrderedVector const&, SVarParamManager const*, eEmailType, unsigned int, int&) ()
>       0x0000000000567f8d in SSessionTask::sendPostSessionEmailForDTM(SSessionInfo*) ()
>       0x0000000000568a96 in SSessionTask::finishImpl() ()
>       0x0000000000595665 in STask::finish() ()
>       0x0000000000565f42 in SSessionTask::handlePrepareLBGroupNotification(STaskLBJobRequest*, ILBResult 
>       const*, ILBRequestBase::EILBEvent, PmUString const&) ()
>       0x0000000000566c85 in SSessionTask::handleLBNotification(STaskLBGroup*, STaskLBJobRequest*, 
>       ILBResult*&, ILBRequestBase::EILBEvent, PmUString const&) ()
>       0x0000000000582fc0 in SWorkflow::handleLBNotification(STask*, STaskLBGroup*, STaskLBJobRequest*, 
>       ILBResult*&, ILBRequestBase::EILBEvent, PmUString const&) ()
>       0x00000000004facb2 in SHandleLBNotificationJob::execute()

Comment: Check please if your OS is compatible with the informatica 10x recommended software/hardware requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracing level in Informatica defines the amount of data you wish to write in the session log when you execute the workflow. Tracing level is a very important aspect in Informatica as it helps in analyzing the error.

**Terse:** When you set the tracing level as terse, Informatica stores error information and information of rejected records. Terse tracing level occupies less space as compared to normal.

Default tracing level is normal. You can change the tracing level to **terse** to enhance the performance. Tracing level can be defined at an individual transformation level, or you can override the tracing level by defining it at the session level.

Please try to change the tracing level and run the Workflow once again. I hope this resolves your system issue.